# Loading XML with code, generated by XSD2Code

Tags: c#, .net, xsd2code

I am having trouble to get the code, generated by XSD2Code, to load a supposedly valid xml file.

My test case involves generating C# code for the [KML version 2.2.0 schema](http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/) and trying to load a [sample KML file](http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/time/time-stamp-point.kml) with it.

The exception occuring during this test is the following:

> System.InvalidOperationException : There was an error reflecting type 'XSDTest.KmlType'.
>     ----> System.InvalidOperationException : There was an error reflecting property 'NetworkLinkControl'.
>     ----> System.InvalidOperationException : There was an error reflecting type 'XSDTest.NetworkLinkControlType'.
>     ----> System.InvalidOperationException : There was an error reflecting property 'Update'.
>     ----> System.InvalidOperationException : There was an error reflecting type 'XSDTest.UpdateType'.
>     ----> System.InvalidOperationException : There was an error reflecting property 'Items'.
>     ----> System.InvalidOperationException : There was an error reflecting type 'XSDTest.DeleteType'.
>     ----> System.InvalidOperationException : There was an error reflecting property 'Items'.
>     ----> System.InvalidOperationException : There was an error reflecting type 'XSDTest.PlacemarkType'.
>     ----> System.InvalidOperationException : There was an error reflecting property 'author'.
>     ----> System.InvalidOperationException : There was an error reflecting type 'XSDTest.atomPersonConstruct'.
>     ----> System.InvalidOperationException : There was an error reflecting property 'Items'.
>     ----> System.InvalidOperationException : Type of choice identifier 'ItemsElementName' is inconsistent with type of 'Items'. Please use array of System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[XSDTest.ItemsChoiceType, XSDTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].

This happens while creating the XML serializer, within the *auto generated code*:

> new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(KmlType))

When creating the code with XSD2Code, I only changed 3 valeus from their default value of false, to true: Serialization.Enabled, Serialization.EnableEncoding and Serialization.GenerateXmlAttributes.

I am not looking for alternatives as far as loading KML with C# is concerned, but I am looking at a way to automatically generated C# code from a valid schema. It doesn't need to be XSD2Code, so in case there's something more appropriate, feel free to suggest that.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Try to set ChoiceIdentifier value to 'array' instead of 'list' in the XSD2Code parameters.

Comment: I'm using Xml2Code 3.4, and can't find ChoiceIdentifier in the options. Has it been renamed?

Comment: We use XSD2CODE here, not XML2CODE.